# how to set a text in line edit Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am working in c++ Qt Creator. I have a form with `label`s and `lineEdit`s. I would like to set as default in each `lineEdit` a text. It would be more efficient than writing the same stuff each time I run the application. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
void setText( const QString & )
```

You can set it in the constructor or maybe set all those defaults in an `init()` function.

Answer (score 5):

Qt has a concept of properties, and for each property, there's usually a getter and a setter, in your case "Text" (as also displayed in the designer) -> `void setText(QString)`, `QString text()`.

As a serious advice: Learn to use the excellent documentation. Nearly everything in QtCreator lets you open a context-sensitive help via F1. And read some introductions;

Answer (score 0):

Read thorugh the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextedit.html).
Why not just set it to your default value at start? Would be the easiest way if you know how to set a textedit to a value anyhow.

hope this helps, tell me if you need aything more

Comment: i've written my text in the line edit table but each time i run the application it dissapear from the screan

Comment: did you set up a reset function that resets all fields when the app is  started, otherwise jsut set the field value on startup...

Answer (score 0):

When you double click in the UI designer on the `QTextEdit` you can enter a default text which is set every time your application is run.

Alternate you can set the text using `setText(QString)` function in the constructor of your window.